# Nested ListView In Jquery Mobile with mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I create nested list view in Asp.net mvc with jQuery mobile, it has 2 sub view, when i navigate to first subview1 i can return back to main view, but when i navigate from subview1 to subview2 i can not back to subview1, since subview1 is somehow null.

in my layout page i put this script

```
 <script>
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText = "Back";
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnTheme = "a";
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";

    });
</script>
```

the main page is :

```
<script>

$(document).on('click', '[data-rel=back]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var activepage = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");

    if (activepage == "schedule")
        $.mobile.changePage($('#flight'), { transition: "slide", reverse: false });

    if (activepage == "dayFlight") {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#schedule'), { transition: "slide", reverse: false });
    }
});
```

```
<div data-role="page" id="flight" data-add-back-btn="true">
<div data-role="content">
    <ul id="flightListView" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="true">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Schedules", new { from = item.DepartureFrom, to = item.Destination })" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide">
                    <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all">@item.NumberOfFlights</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

the subview1 is:

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="schedule">
<div data-role="content">
    <ul id="scheduleListView" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="false">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("DayFlights", new { from = from, to = to, date = item.Date })" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide">
                    <span class="lg">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Day)</span>
                    <span class="lg number laligned">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</span>
                    <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all">@item.Nof</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

the subview2 is :

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="dayFlight">
<div data-role="content">
    <ul id="dayListView" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@item.AgencyUrl" rel="external" data-ajax="false">
                    <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all">@item.Cap</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

something that i figure out, it is when i navigate to subview1, the mainview and the subview1 both of them are in DOM but then when i navigate to subview2, subview1 will replaced by subview2, so it means when i am at subview2 the subview1 does not exist in DOM.

in all cases $.mobile.activePage.prev('.ui-page'); return null, that is the reason why i decided to use if clause to determine to which page i should navigate back to, however when i want to navigate back from subview2 to subview1 it does not work.

how can i implement this senario?

thanks in advance

Comment: what version of jqm are you using? where do you place `mobileinit` code? you dont need to add `data-add-back-btn="true"` when using `$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;`. check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/caHSR/

Comment: i placed mobileinit in layout page in mvc project, yes as you said data-add-back-btn="true" is not needed anymore, just i add it for test and forget to remove, i use jqm version 1.3.0

Comment: back button will handle transition, you dont need extra JS.